# Entity Framework doesn't add [Key]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a model which is containing this entity:

[image]

Now, when EF btw. the CodeGenerator is generating the Code for this Entity, there is the Annotation for PK missing:

```
public partial class tLieferscheinPos
{
    public int kLieferscheinPos { get; set; }
    public int kLieferschein { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> kBestellPos { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> fAnzahl { get; set; }
}
```

When I run now with creating DbContext with a connectionString (where `eazybusinessEntitis` is the `DbContext`):

```
this.context = new eazybusinessEntities(connStr);
```

EF will always update my Database - or throw the exception (when I remove `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` in `OnModelCreating`):

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'tLieferscheinPos' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.   
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'tLieferscheinPos' is based on type 'tLieferscheinPos' that has no keys defined.
```

When I add `[Key]` to the property `kLieferscheinPos`, it is working correct. But this change will always be overwritten, when I recreate the code from the model.

What can I do to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: Well, isn't `kLieferscheinPos` the **primary key** column in your table?? It **should be**! (and then, I presume, EF will recognize it as key and set the attribute accordingly)

Comment: are you using model first approach in EF?

Comment: If you name the key column kLieferscheinPosID will it generate the key attribute then ?

Comment: It seems like you are using either model first ir database first, if you use model first you have to make the change in your edmx file through the designer. If you use database first you have to create the primary key on your database and than in a second step tell your model to update from databasee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the key within your context class...

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<tablename>().HasKey(e => e.keycolumnname);
 }
```

If you're using a viewmodel, you can declare the [key] there...

```
public class products
{
    [Key]
    public int productid { get; set; }
    ...
}
```